# Authentication proxy

Tags: linux, security, authentication, nginx, proxy

I have deployed an opnesource public webservice (elasticsearch) on my Ubuntu.
Problem is - no security at all (only if you pay).

I've researched a bit about blocking port only to internal requests while allowing external access only through authentication proxy.

The simplest way was nginx with basic authentication.

But what's the best practice in those cases? What are my other options?

Answer (score 0):

This is question would find a better home on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com), but you're likely going to find that you'll want to use `iptables` to block all external IPs on all ports, except for the 'authentication proxy'